# Angular prod build issue when using primitive values in @NgModule providers

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular5

I have a service which has two member variables of simple `Date` type. For example:

```
export class SampleService {

  constructor(
    private _fromDate: Date,
    private _toDate: Date
  ) { }

}
```

Since `Date` is primitive and not a known type to Angular. I am providing a default value for it in my modules `@NgModule` decoration. For example:

```
providers:[{provide:Date, useValue: new Date()}]
```

My application runs fine, including unit tests and also builds using `ng build`. However, my production fails when using `--prod` flag with the following error:

`Can't resolve all parameters for SampleService in src/SampleService.ts: (?,?)`

A bit confused here with this behaviour.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably need to use an injection token instead. https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injectiontoken

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel you are right. Creating an injection token and explicitly using @Inject(DATE) in the constructor solved this issue for me. May I request you to please post this as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm... I don't know why my question got down voted :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical reason why developers will get the `Can't resolve all parameters` error will be from either not registering the service as a provider or they are using some type that Angular can't use after running in the browser (especially after doing an AOT compilation).

To solve the second issue, Angular has a concept of [creating special tokens to use](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injectiontoken) instead of using the type in the dependency injection stuff. If following the instructions in the referenced Angular docs, you would do the following in this case.

**Create and use InjectionToken**

```
import { Inject, Injectable, InjectionToken} from '@angular/core';

export const DATE_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<Date>('date');

@Injectable()
export class SampleService {
  constructor(
    private @Inject(DATE_TOKEN) _fromDate: Date,
    private @Inject(DATE_TOKEN) _toDate: Date
  ) {}
}
```

**Provide Token and Service**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { SampleService, DATE_TOKEN } from './sample.service.ts';

@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [
        ...
        { provide: DATE_TOKEN, useValue: new Date() },
        SampleService
    ]
})
export class SampleModule {
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation along with a code sample. Helped me a lot to clear my confusion.